# Help ! Weyroc / uneven floor needs levelling

Tags: floor, carpentry, sanding, joinery, trim-carpentry

we have had an extension built on the back of an old house and they fitted a floating floor with Weyroc top. We have bifold windows right across and want to put in flooring. Problem is that the floor levels are out by over 2 cm across 7 metres width and so not enough height on one side to take the ply base, screed then tile. We need to reduce the level by a few mm on one side or the tiles will have a lip and trip issue at one side of the doors and we need level access for disabled daughter.

Can we shave the weyroc at all ? Screwed the floor down as far as it will go so no scope there and cant take it up and relay as it will affect newly fitted kitchen :-(   HELP all suggestions appreciated
!!!

Comment: If it is a lip of 2cm just at the door way, would it be possible to place something like 1x6 or 8 piece of wood that is cut/shape so it has a gentle slope.  Could use smaller width wood, but the slope would be slightly more steep.

Comment: It always helps to include  few pictures of what your problem is.

Comment: If this is a recent addition, contact the builder and ask them to fix it. Especially handy if you haven't made the final payment yet.